# gdal_retile projection system not defined properly in GeoTIF metadata

Tags: geoserver, gdal, geotiff-tiff, image-pyramids

I struggle to create a ImagePyramid using gdal to be used in geoserver. Geoserver does not recognize the native proj system. 
I have been playing around a lot but I am not sure where the source of the error is.

I think something is wrong with the meta data because I have to specify the projection system for QGIS to load the raster, so it is not specific to geoserver I suppose. The gdal command I use to create the pyramid is as below.

```
gdal_retile.bat -v -r bilinear -of GTiff -levels 4 -ps 2048 2048 -s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" -targetDir outputfolder ‪raster.tif
```

For some reason I cannot use the ESPG number as -s_srs param so I am using proj4.

Output

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: orto_1_1.tif
Size is 2048, 2048
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["UTM Zone 32, Northern Hemisphere",
    GEOGCS["GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```

Working example

```
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["NUTM32",
    GEOGCS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010042,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```

Since I know the projection system I can set it myself when I load the file i QGIS and it is positioned in the right location. In geoserver native is "UNKNOWN" but I can set a declared projection to my known projection and use force declared as SRS handling option. But I want to reproject my raster and to do that native must be picked up by geoserver so i can reproject to declared..

I am not sure where things go wrong and how I can solve it?
If I use QGIS and export my file and set the projection system of the exported file it is picked up correctly, but my files are large so I want to avoid duplication and would like to solve it programatically using gdal. What am I doing wrong? Is my syntax wrong?

EDIT
Picture showing geoserver when GeoTiff file has it coordinate system badly formatted
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gdal_retile` -s_srs](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_retile.html#cmdoption-gdal-translate-s-srs) option sets the **source** spatial reference system, from your question it is already set as something different. `-s_srs` is for situations when you know the projection of the data but the data (or associated metadata files) doesn't know or is incorrect. So never use this option if there is a projection set.

If you would like to **reproject** the data set (though GeoServer will handle this seamlessly for you) then use [`gdal_warp`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) with the [`-t_srs`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-t-srs) option which will reproject your data **t**o the new projection. Then you can create the pyramid with `gdal_retile` in the new projection.

If GeoServer fails to read the new projection, just set it as the forced projection and all will be well - this section should not be used for reprojection just for making sure GeoServer knows what the projection is.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Not sure if I am mixing up things now, but if I have to define a projection system when I load the original raster into qgis then I can assume it is unkown or incorrect right(which is what I am trying to solve)? I am aiming to have geoserver handle the reprojection for me, but to do that I need geoserver to pick up the native SRS which it currently doesn't, so i can reproject to declared.

Comment: No, all you need to do is tell GeoServer what the correct projection is. Your projection is correct just named or formatted badly. Simply add the epsg:code that matches your projection in the forced box.

Comment: Not sure i get it. I have put the correct espg code already in the forced box (as image show). But by doing that I cannot reproject the layer. If using the layer in a client, then I must request it with a particular epsg, is that what you mean that geoserver handle reprojection seasmlessly? I find it strange that neither gdal_edit or translate with proj4 specified will write the projection to the metadata correctly. But thats not part of this question really.

Comment: You do not reproject the layer, GeoServer will reproject the layer when people make requests. All it needs to know is what is the correct projection (either in the native or forced box).